# Error when trying to install XRDP from Putty

Tags: raspbian, remote, putty

I have my RPi currently plugged into my router via cable. I am pretty sure it is online because I am connecting to it through Putty right now. Now that I am in putty I am trying to install XRDP to establish a remote desktop connection. I used this to install it:

```
sudo apt-get install xrdp
```

But it is throwing me this error:

```
Err http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ wheezy/main tightvncserver armhf 1.3.9-6.4
  Temporary failure resolving 'mirrordirector.raspbian.org'
Err http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ wheezy/main x11-xserver-utils armhf 7.7~3
  Temporary failure resolving 'mirrordirector.raspbian.org'
Err http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ wheezy/main xfonts-base all 1:1.0.3
  Temporary failure resolving 'mirrordirector.raspbian.org'
Err http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ wheezy/main xrdp armhf 0.5.0-2
  Temporary failure resolving 'mirrordirector.raspbian.org'
Failed to fetch http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/pool/main/t/tightvnc/tightvncserver_1.3.9-6.4_armhf.deb  Temporary failure resolving 'mirrordirector.raspbian.org'
Failed to fetch http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/pool/main/x/x11-xserver-utils/x11-xserver-utils_7.7~3_armhf.deb  Temporary failure resolving 'mirrordirector.raspbian.org'
Failed to fetch http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/pool/main/x/xfonts-base/xfonts-base_1.0.3_all.deb  Temporary failure resolving 'mirrordirector.raspbian.org'
Failed to fetch http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/pool/main/x/xrdp/xrdp_0.5.0-2_armhf.deb  Temporary failure resolving 'mirrordirector.raspbian.org'
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

I dont know what to do, I tried pinging another machine on my network and it worked. Is my Raspberry Pi online?

Comment: Try pinging both google and raspbian.org. eg: `ping google.com && ping raspbian.org`. Pinging another machine within your network won't help establish whether or not you have internet connection. You know you are connected to your local network because you are connecting in over SSH, however, there may be an issue with out-going traffic being blocked. Are you behind any proxies of any sort that you know of?

Comment: Says "ping: unkown host google.com"

Comment: Yup. Your Pi isn't actually connected to the outside world. It's connected to your network, but not the actual full internet. If it was, it would be able to ping sites such as google.

Comment: try `ping 8.8.8.8`

Answer (score 1):

This was resolved in the comments. It turns out that the OP, although the Pi was connected to the *local* network - it wasn't actually connected to the internet.

Thus, when they tried to `ping google.com`, they received `ping: unkown host google.com` in response. This confirmed that their Pi wasn't actually connected to the outside world. It was connected to their network, but not the actual full internet. If it was, it would be able to ping sites such as google.

Answer (score 0):

You can test you connected or not. Try `ping www.nba.com`  , if it says 'unknown host' this time try `ping 195.175.114.131` (195.175.114.131 is www.nba.com actually)

You should see output from ping command if your Pi connected. If its not connected, it says '`Request timeout for icmp_seq xxx`'

```
PING 195.175.114.131 (195.175.114.131): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 195.175.114.131: icmp_seq=0 ttl=55 time=8.899 ms
64 bytes from 195.175.114.131: icmp_seq=1 ttl=55 time=8.794 ms
64 bytes from 195.175.114.131: icmp_seq=2 ttl=55 time=8.652 ms
64 bytes from 195.175.114.131: icmp_seq=3 ttl=55 time=8.788 ms
64 bytes from 195.175.114.131: icmp_seq=4 ttl=55 time=8.888 ms
```